# Porting python line to c# code

Tags: c#, python

I'm porting short python code to c#
but I stopped on this line, I don't know what does it mean

```
array.append( ("%x" % value)[-1] )
```

anyone? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This: `"%x" % value` gives you a string containing the `value` number represented in hexadecimal.

The `[-1]` gives you the last character of the above.

`array.append` adds that character to the end of `array` (which is presumably a list).

You can figure this out by messing around with the Python REPL:

```
>>> "%x" % 142
'8e'
>>> ("%x" % 142)[-1]
'e'
>>> array = []
>>> array.append(("%x" % 142)[-1])
>>> array
['e']
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the same of doing it:

```
array.append(str(hex(value))[-1])
```

[`hex()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) converts an integer number (of any size) to a lowercase hexadecimal string prefixed with “0x”.

`[-1]` gives you the last char of a string.